# How can I have paragraph spacing for normal paragraphs, but no paragraph spacing within tables?

Tags: microsoft-word

I configured my "Normal" paragraph style to have 10pt spacing before and after.

Within word tables, however, I would like no (0pt) spacing before and after paragraphs.

The closest I came was by checking the table style paragraph setting called "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style".

This only works to my satisfaction when I have a normal paragraph before a table. If the table comes immediately after a heading, the first cell still has this annoying spacing.

I know I could manually mark the cells of the offending table and override the paragraph spacing, but shouldn't this be achievable with some pretty straightforward style configuration?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I have found a configuration that so far seems to work pretty well:

Standard style: 10pt before, 10pt after

Table style: 'Auto' before, 'Auto' after

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Comment: For those who wonder the tickbox in English is "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" -- totally not an obvious solution, but works perfectly for me.  Thanks!

Comment: I had a Master Document messing up the paragraph spacing for a sub-document that was formatted properly. I could edit the Master to fix it, then save it, but when I closed and re-opened the doc... it had overriden the paragraph spacing again!! Took a while to figure out the "Don't add space..." was the issue! Oh so very annoying and tedious. I hate you MS Word, with a passion...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't tried this already, consider creating a separate paragraph style for table Paragraphs.  Apply it to the first one, others should follow, or apply globally to the table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not a 100% sure, but I _think_ I already tried what you're suggesting. I updated my question with a screenshot to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style for tables that is based on the regular style. "MyTableNormal". Edit the new style to override the spacing options - spacing before 0pt, spacing after 0pt. You'll get no vertical spacing but the table contents will otherwise be styled the same as un-tabled text. If you update Normal to use Arial instead of Calibri or size 9 instead of 11.5, etc., the MyTableNormal-styled table contents will update to match, and keep the right spacing.